# Send xml file using curl script

Tags: java, xml, curl

I'm trying to insert data to my local DB using a XML file. Actually I did it using postman client in chrome, I put the XML definition and I gave my service URL send it by POST and in work fine.

Now I'm trying to do it with curl commandline, this is the line that I'm using:

```
curl -F "file=@/Users/Jonathan/Documents;filename=variable.xml" 127.0,0.1:8080/WU-BDP-MetadataManagement/v1/variables
```

Where `file@` is the path to my XML file and `variable.xml` is my file name next to my service URL but this is not working.

Some advice of what im doing wrong?

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the whole directory instead of file `/Users/Jonathan/Documents` and it should be something like `/Users/Jonathan/Documents/variable.xml`

So your overall command will be

```
curl -F "file=@/Users/Jonathan/Documents/variable.xml;filename=variable.xml" 127.0,0.1:8080/WU-BDP-MetadataManagement/v1/variables
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, It work's fine, actually I try this one: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d @variable.xml 127.0,0,1:8080/WU-BDP-MetadataManagement/v1/variables -v; I put my xml file in the same directory where I was running the Curl command and it works to!